# Stripe Detach Payment Method of a customer under Connect

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe payment and I'm quite new at it. I can detach payment methods of the regular customers. I can even delete the regular customers, programmatically.

The problem is I cannot detach payment methods of the **Customers** under the `Connect` account. I cannot delete the **Customers** under the `Connect` account either. I can do this via the dashboard, though.

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a platform account, you can make calls to your connected account by using the `Stripe-Account` header, as [explained here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication).

Fo example, to delete a customer of a connected account in dotNET, you would do something like this:

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "{{PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}}";

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.StripeAccount = "{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}";

var service = new CustomerService();
service.Delete("cus_xxx", null, requestOptions);
```